# About Accepted Rate

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, accept-rate

Throughout the Maths questions, we can see many answers which have not been voted as desired or corrected ones yet. Do we need an alert or something on the page notifying the questioners pick the best answer soon? Note me please if this was asked before in any other ways. Thanks.

Comment: If the best answer is not good enough, it is better not to pick any answer. If a user has a low accepted rate, someone will often comment on it. If someone posted hundred questions with lots of answers, but didn't accept any, it's a bad sign. But it doesn't mean that each of these questions shold be considered answered.

Comment: You can't force people to accept an answer; this discussion comes up every once and a while on [metase] and it's always denied with the same response.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore: I see what are you saying. Maybe I didn't note my aim of this question properly. Anyway, Gerry did it well. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need an alert - but there's nothing wrong with someone leaving a comment politely inquiring as to whether the questioner has had time to consider the answers on offer, whether the questioner would like to ask for some particular point to be further clarified, etc., etc.

Comment: And sometimes a less-polite comment too...

Comment: Yes. The point you noted was what I needed to know Gerry. Thanks for the time.